# vb.net Button - Align Left inside <td>

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I tried to align the button to left in the below code for Button ID="UiButtonAddCharacteristics".I couldn't align it to the left side of the form. Request help .Thanks

```
                           <b>Characteristics:</b><asp:Label ID="UiLabelProcesssType" Visible="false" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="  (Please select Type of Process)"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>

                                            <table border='0' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" "width: 100%; height: 81px; border:1px; >
                                            <tr>


                                                                                         <td>
                                                &nbsp<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="Submit" InitialValue=""
                                                   SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="RdblAutomotiveType" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
                                            </td>

                                            <td align ="left"> 
                                            <br/>
                                            <br />

                                        <asp:Button ID="UiButtonAddCharacteristics" CausesValidation="false"  runat="server"
                                            Text="+" ToolTip="Add new fgfitem" SkinID="BtnPlusMinus" ></asp:Button>
                                              <asp:Button ID="UiButtonRemoveCharacteristics" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"
                                               Text="-" ToolTip="Remove item" SkinID="BtnPlusMinus"></asp:Button>

                                            </td>
                                            <td> &nbsp
                                           </tr>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The align attribute of `<td>` is deprecated in HTML5. Use CSS instead. See https://html.com/attributes/td-align/ for an example.